# Entity Framework Core Keyless Navigation Problem

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm building a proof of concept for my company. We have an existing platform that we will be replacing in pieces with modern technologies. Currently I'm restricted to using our existing databases which have several keyless tables. I'm building a Blazor WebAssembly application which is calling to a .net core web application using gRPC. My problem is I'm using EF Core to communicate with the existing databases but I get an exception when calling `DbContext.Attach(shipment)`

```
"The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'Document'. Navigations can only target entity types with keys."
```

`Document` is a navigation property on the entity being `Attach`ed to the `DbContext`.

`Shipment` is a very large and complex data structure going many layers deep. Is there a way to avoid having to set the entity state for each entity, `DbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added`, within the model's structure?

Or possibly map the CRUD operations of the DbSet to stored procedures?

**EDIT**

Here is a drastically shortened version of the schema, but this is all that is pertinent to the problem.

```
public class Shipment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // 60 other properties

    public virtual ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public int ShippingId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public virtual Shipment Shipment { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to attach the `Shipment` entity to the `DbContext`, or manually set its state, I get the exception above.

Again, I cannot change the database schema at this time and there are many other models similar to `Document` which do not have a key or a means of adding one.

**EDIT 2**

I realize this needs further explanation. Obviously, the `DbContext` would not be able to Insert/Update/Delete since, without a key, it wouldn't know how. All I need is to be able to read when getting the `Shipping` entity and having the navigation property `Documents` be set. But when saving `Shipping`, just ignore the navigation property completely.

Comment: Do you have a schema or database diagram you could share? I'm struggling to understand how you want a navigation property for a keyless table to work.

Comment: Consider reading [Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types) documentation. They have many limitations, and basically can be used only for data reading, but not for add/update/delete. i.e. only the R part of the CRUD.

Comment: As the error suggests, add a Key to your Document entity. You may use Data annotations `[Key]` to denote a property as a pk.

Comment: @LinkedListT as I stated above a few times, I cannot change the database schema.

Comment: We are not asking to change the schema in the database.  Entity has a mapping file (the model) that links the database objects to the c# classes.  The model needs to be updated.

Comment: To make sure I'm understanding correctly, I need to add a property to the `Document` model and tell the `DbContext` that it is the PK, even though that new property doesn't have a backing field in the database?

Comment: Ive been thinking about this question for a couple of days, and entity Framework is not designed to handle legacy schemas. I think you should consider a different orm, such as dapper: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In trying to prove @jdweng wrong, and generate an exception I've seen many times when the Entity model does not have backing fields in the database, I stumbled upon this solution.

I added `public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();` to all my keyless entities and then replaced `entity.HasNoKey();` with `entity.HasAlternateKey(x => x.Id);` using the `ModelBuilder`.

`HasAlternateKey`'s Summary: Creates an alternate key in the model for this entity type if one does not already exist over the specified properties. This will force the properties to be read-only.

This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How to add the new property `Id` to the model, without to exclude it from mapping in the `EntityTypeBuilder` like `builder.Ignore(e => e.Id)`?

Comment: @user3231784 You're grammar is confusing. You do or do not want to exclude the `Id` from being mapped to the database?

Comment: Sorry about the grammar. I've a similar problem and I understood that you have added a new property `Id` to the model class to define a key. Whereas the keyless database table does not contain such a column.  If so, I thought that `entity.Ignore(e => e.Id)` should be required? And I wondered if in this case `entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Id)` can be defined? But perhaps I have misunderstood.

Comment: @user3231784 You do not need to call `entity.Ignore(e => e.Id)` as `entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Id)` already does that. However, it makes the object completely read-only.

Comment: My problem was I was trying to save an object to the database but it contained a collection of keyless objects. EF didn't have a way to determine if the child objects were new or already existed so it threw an Exception. With `entity.HasAlternateKey(e => e.Id)`, the child objects are ignored completely. Not saved or updated.

Comment: When I try this solution, I get this exception: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Id'.` But I'm on dotnet 6, so things might have changed

Answer (score 0):

If that Document class reflects the complete schema for the document table then you cannot, and probably should not attempt to associate the documents via EF navigation properties. While a schema can function perfectly fine with a 1 way relationship from a table that does not have a PK, EF cannot manage a relationship that way. How exactly can you expect to differentiate one document from another?  The system may never really need to, but as an ORM designed to reliably load and manage data, that is a requirement.

Normally where a table does not have a PK, you can satisfy EF by defining a key provided there are enough fields to uniquely differentiate records. For example ShippingId + CreatedAt and possibly CreatedBy if needed. However, with your outlined schema there is only the binary content which cannot serve as part of the key.

If you cannot adjust the schema to introduce a meaningless key (all tables should have a PK) then I would say your only option is to remove the association as far as EF is concerned and load documents by Shipment completely separately. With potentially large binary data that is rarely used, having navigation properties can be potentially hazardous  as attempting to `Include` them or having their lazy load proxy tripped unexpectedly by something like a serializer can paralyze a system.

Comment: I agree with everything you're saying and assumed this to ultimately be the case. However, there are dozens of navigation properties within the `Shipment` entity or nested further down. So I am hoping there is a way to get all these values when reading to avoid manually making dozens of additional calls to load all the read-only fields.

Comment: As long as a related entity has a PK, or at least enough fields to uniquely identify a row and can be configured as a Key in EF then you can utilize navigation properties. It would just be entities like Document that lack that an identifier that you would need to leave off and handle separately. If these types of tables are common I would explore why schema modification isn't allowed. You don't need to add a PK to tables to satisfy this, only a unique (and preferably indexed) identity column that EF can map as a Key. Most DBs can append and populate these automatically.

Comment: Schema modification is not an option immediately as we have hundreds of clients and this type of change globally would be too intensive.